# Highlighting a day in CalendarView XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, calendar, calendarview

To practice creating UWP applications, I am creating a library system with user logins. Once a user logs in they are greeted with a screen containing a calendar of their book return dates. I want to highlight the days on the calendar which their books are due. Once they click on a book, it will load a popup containing the book information.

I have a function to populate the calendar with the highlighted dates but I cannot figure out how to highlight a particular calendar item.

CS:

```
private void PopulateCalendar()
    {
        User user = PageController.loggedIn;

        List<DateTimeOffset> highlightedDates = new List<DateTimeOffset>();
        foreach (Loan loan in user.Loans)
        {
            highlightedDates.Add(loan.ReturnDate);
        }

        //highlight the dates
    }
```

XAML:

```
<Page
x:Class="FirstUWPProject.UserPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:FirstUWPProject"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" d:DesignWidth="1280" d:DesignHeight="720">

<Grid>
    <Button x:Name="logOutButton" Margin="1040,610,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="60" Width="160"
            Click="LogOutClicked"
            Content="Log Out" FontSize="20" CornerRadius="10,10,10,10"/>
    <Button x:Name="homeButton" Margin="80,610,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="60" Width="160"
            Click="HomeClickedUser"
            Content="Home" FontSize="20" CornerRadius="10,10,10,10"/>
    <CalendarView  x:Name="calendarView" Margin="800,80,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="400" Width="400" SelectedDatesChanged="CalendarViewSelectedDatesChanged"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Does my soluton work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[CalendarView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.calendarview?view=winrt-22621) doesn't have a property that could let you access the `CalendarViewItem` directly. So if you want to get some specific items of the `CalendarView` and change its color, you might need to use the [DependencyObjectExtensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/extensions/dependencyobjectextensions) from Windows Community Toolkit. This extension exposes several APIs to aid in using the [VisualTreeHelper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.VisualTreeHelper?view=winrt-22621) class. The `VisualTreeHelper` class could go through the Visual Tree at runtime and find the target element for you.

First of all, you have to [install the Windows Community Toolkit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/getting-started) NuGet Package.
Right-click on your project name and select Manage NuGet Packages. Search for **Microsoft.Toolkit.UWP.UI**, then install it.

In the code-behind, add the namespaces to the toolkit:

```
using Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI;
```

Then you could use it to update the `CalendarViewItem`.

```
  private void UpdateCalendarView()
    {
        var calendarViewDays = calendarView.FindDescendants().OfType<CalendarViewDayItem>();
        foreach (var singleDay in calendarViewDays)
        {
            if (highlightedDates.Contains(singleDay.Date.Date))
            {
                //highlight
                singleDay.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
            }
        }
    }
```